# Is it possible to just log every signal received and not change behavior?

Tags: go, signals

I understand how to catch every signal

```
idleConnsClosed := make(chan bool)
SignalChannel := make(chan os.Signal, 1)

// Notify to SignalChannel any signal received
signal.Notify(SignalChannel)

go func() {
    for {
        sig := <-SignalChannel
        log.Notice("Signal %#v received", sig)
        switch sig {
        case syscall.SIGTERM:
            // ok sigterm, I know how to handle with it
            log.Info("ShutDown HTTP server (SIGTERM)")
            if err := server.Shutdown(context.Background()); err != nil {
                // Error from closing listeners, or context timeout:
                log.Error("HTTP server Shutdown: %v", err)
            }
        case syscall.SIGHUP:
            //reinit configurations and do some stuff, I know how to handle this                 
            continue
        case syscall.SIGPIPE:
            //Don't know what to do, just wanted to log it
            continue
        case syscall.SIGABRT:
            //exit with core dump...how to do that ?
            continue
        default:
            // unhandled signal?, ok how to not change it's behavior?
            log.Warning("Unhandled Signal %s received!", sig)
        }
        close(idleConnsClosed)
    }
}()
```

In general I just want to

1. handle some understandable signals - X
2. log every signal I get - Y
3. do not change the behaviors of Y - X signals

Answer (score 1):

`Notify` disables the default behaviour for a given set of asynchronous signals and instead delivers them over one or more registered channels. I think that means that you can't intercept the signal without changing its behaviour.

The [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/os/signal/#hdr-Default_behavior_of_signals_in_Go_programs) describe default behaviour:

> By default, a synchronous signal is converted into a run-time panic. A SIGHUP, SIGINT, or SIGTERM signal causes the program to exit. A SIGQUIT, SIGILL, SIGTRAP, SIGABRT, SIGSTKFLT, SIGEMT, or SIGSYS signal causes the program to exit with a stack dump

It should be possible to capture the signal, handle it, then emulate default behaviour appropriate to that signal.

Comment: could you please explain for example how to emulate SIGABRT behaviour ?

Comment: SIGABRT causes the program to exit with a stack dump - perhaps a `panic` in your SIGABRT switch clause would be sufficient. It won't be exactly the same behaviour but might be good enough for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

i think you want below code. The code has only a skeleton.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    done := make(chan bool)
    channel := make(chan os.Signal, 1)

    signal.Notify(channel)

    go func() {
        for sig := range channel {

            switch sig {
            case syscall.SIGTERM:
                fmt.Printf("SIGTERM Signal %s received!\n", sig)
            case syscall.SIGHUP:
                fmt.Printf("SIGHUP Signal %s received!\n", sig)
            case syscall.SIGPIPE:
                fmt.Printf("SIGPIPE Signal %s received!\n", sig)
            case syscall.SIGABRT:
                fmt.Printf("SIGABRT Signal %s received!\n", sig)
            default:
                fmt.Printf("Unhandled Signal %s received!\n", sig)
                done <- true
            }
        }
    }()

    <-done
}
```

code updated.

Comment: in your example in case of Signal Abort nothing would happen
even if you comment case syscall.SIGABRT: after Signal Abort program will exit with code 0 and without corde dump to stderr

the correct behavior is to exit with 2 code with core dump information into stderr...

Comment: i find https://golang.org/src/os/signal/doc.go, line 62. ```Notify disables the default behavior for a given set of asynchronous
signals and instead delivers them over one or more registered
channels. Specifically, it applies to the signals SIGHUP, SIGINT,
SIGQUIT, SIGABRT, and SIGTERM.```